# Need suggestions how to add hide/unhide and pin/unpin features on tooltip of bar graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts, echarts-for-react

I Wanted to implement pin/unpin and hide/unhide feature on bar chart using echart-for-react.
suggest me a way, so i can implement it my react component
please find below configuration object for chart.
*sample_data is array with numbers.

```
chartOptions = {
    tooltip: {
        triggerOn: 'click',
        trigger: 'axis',
        enterable: true,
        formatter: (params) => {
            const pin = '<button className="tooltip-action">pin</button>';
            const Content = `${`${params?.[0].marker} ${params[0].name}`}<br>
        mape: ${params[0].value}`;
            return Content;
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
        data: sample_data,
        axisLabel: {
            show: false
        }
    }],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        triggerEvent: true
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: chartData,
            type: 'bar',
            smooth: true,
            selectedMode: 'single',
            label: {
                show: true,
                position: 'right'
            }
        }
    ],
    toolbox: {
        show: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {},
            dataZoom: {}
        }
    }
};
<ReactECharts option={chartOptions} renderer='canvas'/>
```